# Scala's non curly braced IF statement

Tags: scala, syntax

One thing I love about Scala is that they give you multiple ways to write your statements, but this also raises some questions for me.

I have been fiddling around with a simple if statement, and discovered that it's behaviour is not as I would expect it to be. Have a look at the following code snippet:

```
var a = 0
var b = 0

if(false)
  a += 1
  b += 1

println(a) // 0
println(b) // 1
```

In this small example I would assume that both a and b will be zero at the end of the script, but this is not the case. It does work like I would expect when I add curly braces to the if statement.

It might be that I'm missing something here, but to me this seems like a rather confusing syntax. It could be easily overlooked when debugging someone else's code, so I am very curious about the reasons behind this syntax style.

Any opinions / explanations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for `if` is (simplified):

```
if (<bool expr>) <expr> [else <expr>]
```

Your

```
if(false)
  a += 1
  b += 1
```

is understood as

```
if (false) a += 1
b += 1
```

because `a += 1` is an expression. Maybe it is clearer with curly braces

```
if (false) {
  a += 1
}
b += 1
```

Note that block of code is an expression as well that evaluates to whatever last expression inside it evaluates to. So to have both expressions inside the if you need to put them in a block

```
if (false) {
  a += 1
  b += 1
}
```

There is of course no python-like block definition through indentation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I new see that whitespace is not significant in Scala, and so I should have added curly braces. The code snippets provided by you really made this clear, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Why? It makes perfect sense. Scala is not like python with significant white space (actually your snippets look a lot like python ;)). If you want your ***if*** to govern multiple statements you need curly braces.

In languages that work like this, style guides often recommend always using a curly brace after an ***if*** to avoid the exact confusion you are taking about.

Personally, I have no problem with ***if*** statements followed by a single line and no curly brace.

Comment: As a newcomer I made the assumption that you could use indentation for the expressions included in an if, but I now see that this is not the case. So from now on I would just stick with curly braces, that way I won't get confused! Thanks for your fast & clear answer!